# Middleware to Encrypt Query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, middleware

I am writing a .Net Core Middleware to encrypt the query string parameters, where I want to user to see something like 
?enc=VXzal017xHwKKPolDWQJoLACDqQ0fE//wGkgvRTdG/GgXIBDd1
while the code sees this
?user=123&account=456.

I encrypt the params using a IDataProtector. The Invoke() in my middleware looks like the below code

```
if (UriHelper.GetEncodedUrl(context.Request).Contains("?"))
        {
            string query = ExtractQuery((context.Request.GetEncodedUrl()));

            int indexOfEnc = query.IndexOf(PARAMETER_NAME, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            if (indexOfEnc > -1)
            {

                var enc = context.Request.Query[PARAMETER_NAME];
                enc = Decrypt(enc);
                context.Request.Path = new PathString(context.Request.Path.Value + enc);
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }

            else if (context.Request.Method == "GET" || context.Request.Method == "POST")
            {
                // Encrypt the query string and redirects to the encrypted URL.
                // Remove if you don't want all query strings to be encrypted automatically.
                string encryptedQuery = Encrypt(query);
                string tempRawUrl = UriHelper.GetEncodedUrl(context.Request).ToLower();
                if (!(context.Request.Method == "POST" && tempRawUrl.Contains("ha")))
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.Path.Value + "?" + PARAMETER_NAME +  "=" + encryptedQuery);
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
```

The First time when I login and enter the user/pass, the code comes in to the elseif section above and gets encrypted fine. I look for the "enc" query param the next time and while it gets decrypted and the path looks good, the

```
**await _next.Invoke(context);**
```

in the if section does nothing. I am expecting it to go to the controller to validate the user/pass.

Bear with me here please, this is my first middleware and I am trying to replace the httphandlers in my legacy code.

Any help is appreciated. I have spent almost 5 hours on this and cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Not related to your question, but what problem are you trying to solve by encrypting the query string?

Comment: We might have to pass a client specific secret Key in the query string as well as a client ID and don't want that to be going in as plain text.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? Actually I given a try to your code and its working with an issue i.e Tempdata loss on redirection. Could you please share your code if it has been done, I am also lookin for same.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the `IQueryFeature` and the `IResponseFeature`. In ASP.NET Core, features allow to override behaviours of basics objects 
like HttpRequest & HttpResponse object.

You could simply wrap the existing `IQueryFeature` for transparent decryption. 
And for the query encryption, wrap the existing `IResponseFeature` for transparent encryption. 
Set the wrappers within the middleware.

```
httpContext.Features.Set<IQueryFeature>(new TransparentDecryptionQueryFeature(httpContext.Features.Get<IQueryFeature>));
httpContext.Features.Set<IResponseFeature>(new TransparentEncryptionResponseFeature(httpContext.Features.Get<IResponseFeature>));
```

By doing so, all middlewares executing after yours will use the "Transparent Feature".

```
public class TransparentDecryptionQueryFeature : IQueryFeature
{
    privare readonly IQueryCollection _store;

    public TransparentDecryptionQueryFeature(IQueryFeature feature)
    {
        _store = new TranparentDecryptionQueryCollection(feature.Query);
    }

    public IQueryCollection Query
    {
        get
        {
            return _store;
        }

        set
        {
            _store = new TransparentDecryptionQueryCollection(value);
        }
    }
}

public class TransparentDecryptionQueryCollection : IQueryCollection
{
    private readonly IQueryCollection _inner;

    public TransparentDecryptionQueryCollection(IQueryCollection inner)
    {
         var store = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>()
         foreach (var item in inner)
         {
             if (item.Key == PARAMETER_NAME)
             {
                 // TODO : Adds all the decrypted query parameters in the store
             }
             else
             {
                 store.Add(item);
             }
         }
         _inner = new QueryCollection(store);
    }

    // implement other methods by delegating with _inner object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to.

```
if (indexOfEnc > -1)
            {

                var enc = context.Request.Query[PARAMETER_NAME];
                enc = "?" + Decrypt(enc);
                Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.QueryString queryString = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.QueryString(enc);
                    context.Request.QueryString = queryString;

                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
```

and it does work now. I still think I am missing something here. Is there a better way to do this ?